# nginx -t not throwing error when including non existing directory

Tags: nginx

I need nginx to fail when a directory which uses a `*` does not exist.

When `conf.d` directory does not exist the line;

```
include /path/to/conf.d/*.conf;
```

passes when running `nginx -t`.

I am completely aware that the reason the line doesn't cause an error, is because `nginx` uses `glob` when a wilcard is used. It simply finds no files, doesn't include them, then passses the test. How can I make `nginx -t` succeed when there are no files in the directory but fail when the directory does not exist?

Is that even possible, without having creating an empty file in `conf.d` and including that or using an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem using `str_replace` in `php`.

```
$files = glob('/path/to/nginx/files/*');
$toFind = $dirName.'/*';
$toReplace = $dirName.'/';
$editedFiles = [];
$editedFilesContents = [];
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
        $temp = file_get_contents($file);
        $contents = str_replace($toFind, $toReplace, $temp, $count);
        if ($count > 0)
        {
            $editedFiles[] = $file;
            $editedFilesContents[] = $temp;
            file_put_contents($file, $contents);
        }
    }
}
$error = exec('/usr/sbin/nginx -t', $output);
foreach ($editedFiles as $i => $file)
    file_put_contents($file, $editedFilesContents[$i]);
```

It may seem like overkill for such a trivial problem but it allows me to delete and rename folders in my nginx configuration page without the risking of breaking my site.